# How to pass parameters from Execution context to MultiResourcePartitioner

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, partitioning

I have been following chapter eleven of this book:
[https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484237236#:~:text=The%20Definitive%20Guide%20to%20Spring%20Batch%20covers%20how,5%2C%20and%20the%20new%20Spring%20Boot%202%20micro-framework](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484237236#:%7E:text=The%20Definitive%20Guide%20to%20Spring%20Batch%20covers%20how,5%2C%20and%20the%20new%20Spring%20Boot%202%20micro-framework).

I am trying to implement a multiresourcepartitioner. Now this is the code I'm using:

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public MultiResourcePartitioner multiResourcePartitioner(@Value("#{jobParameters['inputFiles']}")Resource[] resources){
        MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
        partitioner.setKeyName("file");
        partitioner.setResources(resources);
        return partitioner;
    }
```

This is supposed to send to each step the name of a file to read and process.
In order to pass the parameters I am doing the following:

```
Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        JobParameter parameter = new JobParameter(new Date());
        parameters.put("currentTime", parameter);

        parameters.put("inputFiles", new JobParameter("1.csv;2.csv"));
```

But when I debug the MultiResourcePartitioner class all I'm seeing is :

[image]

Does anybody know what's the syntax to get an array of resources as input to the MultiResourcePartitioner class?

All the book says is the following:
"The other value we need to set on this Partitioner is that array of
Resources. Once that is done, we can return the instance"

Comment: You can pass a job parameter as a String with a wildcard matching all files, something like `parameters.put("inputFiles", new JobParameter("/data/*.csv"));`. Spring will convert them to an array of resources. You can find an example here: https://github.com/mminella/scaling-demos/tree/master/partitioned-demo. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: parameters.put("inputFiles", new Parameter("\\multifile\\\*.csv")); Doesn't work, the array of resources is just empty. I had to change the separators because I'm on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Bean public MultiResourcePartitioner multiResourcePartitioner(@Value("classpath:multifile/*csv") Resource[] externalResources){ MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner(); partitioner.setKeyName("file"); partitioner.setResources(externalResources); return partitioner; }`

I had to get rid of the SpEL that didn't work at all, couldn't even read a single file. I realized the partitioner doesn't need the beanscope (it doesn't use it when reading from a database with multiple threads), so I just passed the array of resources to the bean and it worked.